# Set the image upload size

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am trying to limit the upload file size to 1MB using the following jQuery code :

```
<td><label> Upload image </label>
  <input type="file" class="upload" name="image" value="<?php echo set_value('image'); ?>" /> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change','.upload',function(){
      files = this.files;
      size = files[0].size;
        //max size 50kb => 50*1000
      if( size > 1000141) {
        alert('Please upload less than 1mb file');
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
</script>
```

When I upload a file greater than 1MB, it displays the error message but the upload goes through successfully. What's causing this?

Comment: You alert "Please upload less than 1mb file" and return false. But why should this exit the upload?

Comment: @Tobias yes , i alert  "Pleas upload less than 1 mb file" . But   when i upload the file greater than 1mb , uploaded that image. Whats the issue?

Comment: @maytham  i alert  "Please upload less than 1 mb file"  thats working correctly. The issue is that imge is uploaded  if the size is  more than 1 mb. Please provide  solution for this  issue?

Comment: start with something simple. After `size = files[0].size;`, add `console.log(size);` and check what response you get to your console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden field to set the max size.

```html
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
```

The field must be before the input type=file.
But be careful its easy to bypass the MAX_FILE_SIZE.
You should also check the file size with php.

```
$size= $_FILES["myfile"]["size"];
if($size > 1000141) 
{
 //dont upload file
}
else {
 //upload file
}
```

Comment: thanks for the information @tobias  is this code   enough  for  limit  the upload size? is the above jquery  needed  along with this  php code?

Comment: No you dont need the javascript. The input field with the max_file_size will do the same. In the PHP check you can make a error message with "echo" or so.

Comment: thanks  for the reply.  When i  using the php   for  limit the size of  the image  ,its not working  proprly

Comment: how to set the  image upload size in codeigniter? Please provide  a suitable code for this  .

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html Look in the Controller (do_upload)

Comment: i set the size  limite to 1 mb.when i upload the file , if  size is greater than 1mb  then the image is uploaded in to database .  but the image is not in the  folder  whats causing this?

Comment: When i upload the file using Ci , upload goes through successfully,, alert is not display in this case Please proviide solution for this issue